# Nextjs using process.env with dynamic variable name

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js

I have a webapp in Nextjs both in server and client mode, access to process.env like this always returns me "undefined":

.env file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY_ES=Euros
NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY_MX=Pesos
NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY_GB=Pounds

CURRENCY_ES=Euros
CURRENCY_MX=Pesos
CURRENCY_GB=Pounds
```

Code:

```
//Client side 
//country can be: ES, MX, GB
const varName = "NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY_" + country.toUpperCase();
console.log(process.env[varName]); // this returns undefined
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENCY_ES); // this prints "Euros"



//Server side 
//country can be: ES, MX, GB
const varName = "CURRENCY_" + country.toUpperCase();
console.log(process.env[varName]); // this returns undefined
console.log(process.env.CURRENCY_ES); // this prints "Euros"
```

How can I get the process.env[varName] with a valid value? not undefined? varName must a variable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access those properties dynamically as you did, since Next.js uses [webpack's DefinePlugin](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/f06c58911515d980e25c33874c5f18ade5ac99df/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables.md) to "string replace" them.

Why do you use env variables for currency, does they depends on the env the app runs? If no, use just regular POJO (Plain Old Javascript Object) as a constant that can be imported from all the places.

```js
// currencies.js

export const currencies = {
  es: 'Euros',
  mx: 'Pesos',
  gb: 'Pounds',
};

// otherModule.js
import { currencies } from './path-to/currencies.js';

console.log(currencies.es); // will print "Euros"
```

Best practice to use `env` variables are for variables that are "config" or env dependent values such as paths / accessKey / tokens.